# Use mipmap for Parse notification

Tags: android, user-interface, parse-platform

Im using

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
      android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

inside my manifest but I get:

```
Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi (at line 238)
```

1. What does this mean?
2. Whats the notification image preferred size?
3. Notification image dont use device screen resolution for images?

Comment: Any help on this one?

Comment: @Diego theres no other way to set the push icon (sent from parse GUI) but the warning is still there.